# Convert CSV to Parquet in S3 with Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, parquet

I need convert a CSV file to Parquet file in S3 path. I'm trying use the code below, but no error occurs, the code execute with success and dont convert the CSV file

```
import pandas as pd
import boto3
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

s3 = boto3.client("s3", region_name='us-east-2', aws_access_key_id='my key id',
                  aws_secret_access_key='my secret key')

obj = s3.get_object(Bucket='my bucket', Key='test.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(obj['Body'])
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
pq.write_to_dataset(table=table, root_path="test.parquet")
```

Comment: Instead of doing it yourself, would you consider using Amazon Athena to convert the file formats? See: [Converting to Columnar Formats - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/convert-to-columnar.html)

Comment: Only this script dont work: pq.write_to_dataset(table=table, root_path="test.parquet")
Not creating the parquet file on s3

Comment: There is no code in your program that would write data to S3. I can see that it is reading a CSV file into a Pandas dataframe, but there is nothing that would _write_ to S3.

Comment: it's being writen locally to a file called test.parquet. You then have to upload that file to parquet.

Answer (score 1):

**AWS CSV to Parquet Converter in Python**

This Script gets files from Amazon S3 and converts it to Parquet Version for later query jobs and uploads it back to the Amazon S3.

```
import numpy 
import pandas 
import fastparquet

def lambda_handler(event,context):

    #identifying resource
    s3_object = boto3.client('s3', region_name='us-east-2')

    #access file

    get_file = s3_object.get_object(Bucket='ENTER_BUCKET_NAME_HERE', Key='CSV_FILE_NAME.csv')
    
    get = get_file['Body']

    df = pandas.DataFrame(get)

    #convert csv to parquet function
    def conv_csv_parquet_file(df):
    
        converted_data_parquet = df.to_parquet('converted_data_parquet_version.parquet')
    
    conv_csv_parquet_file(df)

    print("File converted from CSV to parquet completed")

    #uploading the parquet version file

    s3_path = "/converted_to_parquet/" + converted_data_parquet

    put_response = s3_resource.Object('ENTER_BUCKET_NAME_HERE',converted_data_parquet).put(Body=converted_data_parquet)
```

Python Library Boto3 allows the lambda to get the CSV file from S3 and then Fast-Parquet (or Pyarrow) converts the CSV file into Parquet.

From- https://github.com/ayshaysha/aws-csv-to-parquet-converter.py